# Get synonym or root word from solr

Tags: java, database, data-structures, solr

I have a list of synonyms like below

```
"gb":["gib","gigabyte"],
"happy":["glad","joyful"],
"television":["tv"]
```

I need to convert sentence 1 to sentence 2

1. I like watching tv
2. I like watching television

Is there a synonym API in solar to which if I pass "tv" can give back "television"

what approaches can be taken to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

if you are thinking of using Solr just for this, it would be much much easier just not to. Bringing the whole Solr just for this makes no sense.

Just use a data structure of your choosing (depending on what are your needs it could be a list of hashmaps, [a multimap from guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)...) to store the dictionary data, and use plain java.

Comment: thank you fro the inputs, we have solar already being used by our team, so thought of leveraging the infrastructure.